# Почему в mozilla со второго раза срабатывает событие esc?

Tags: javascript, jquery

В *Chrome* срабатывает с первого раза, а в *Firefox* со 2-го раза, почему? Как можно это исправить, чтобы во всех браузерах срабатывало с первого раза?

```
$(document).on('keyup', function( event ) {
   if(event.keyCode === 27) {
      alert('Esc key pressed.');      
   }
});
```

Comment: У меня в Firefox с первого раза срабатывает, попробуйте обновить браузер, почистить хеш и про дебажить.

Comment: Нужно смотреть весь код. У меня была проблема с Firefox`ом, не срабатывали нажатия клавиш после того, как я отключал работу некоторых клавиш режимом "disable". Пришлось отключать через функции. Как это у них работает не знаю, но искать ошибку нужно в остальных частях кода

Comment: Версия ff? У меня не воспроизводится.
Плюс как заметили сверху, если у вас ошибка проявляется на рабочем коде а не на минимальном примере, есть множество нюансов. Например включенный автокомплит как одна из штук, приходящих мне в голову.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
$(document).keypress(function( event ) {
   if((event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which) == 27) {
      alert('Esc key pressed.');  
      return false;    
   }
});
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996449/jquery-keyup-working-in-all-browsers-except-firefox

Comment: также с 2 го раза

Comment: после выхода из полноэкранного режима не срабатывает сразу, в обычном режиме, да, срабатывает